# jQuery Detect Duplicate Url's?

Tags: jquery, input

I have 3 input boxes like:

```
<input id="0" type="text" class="test" />
<input id="1" type="text" class="test"/>
<input id="2" type="text" class="test"/>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can detect duplicate data such it would alert the user if they entered the SAME url in >1 any of the boxes ?

I have jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PLacj/.

Can anyone assist ?

Comment: Do you want to consider `www.google.com`, `http://www.google.com`, and `google.com` to be the same url?

Comment: @Tom -- it is best (and correct) to **not** have id's start with a number.

Comment: @sam dufel - yeah i considered REGEX but wasn't sure whether it was the best option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('.test').blur(function() {
    var self = this;
     var value = this.value;
    $('.test').not(this).each(function(){
        if(value == this.value && this.value.length > 0){
            alert('cannot do that!');
            self.value = '';
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PLacj/2/

Comment: @Tom -- just saying `+1` doesn't mean anything. remember -- if you found your answer, upvote it, and when you can, mark it as accepted :-)

Comment: yeah I would but I can't accept the answer yet as SO doesn't allow it for 10 mins or something :)

Comment: This do not check the case while comparing values.

Comment: @Shankar -- what do you mean?

Comment: @Neal - You code will allow the same value in lower and upper case.

Comment: @Shankar -- i do not see a problem with that. the OP never said it was not case sensitive or otherwise.

Comment: @Neal - That is also true. But generally while comparing urls we should compare them case insensitive.

Comment: @Neal - any chance to update it to support ? :) Would provide a more complete answer i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PLacj/3/)**

```
$(function(){

   $('.test').blur(function() {
       var isDup = false, val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
       $('.test').not("#"+this.id).each(function(){
           if($(this).val().toLowerCase() == val){
               isDup = true;
           }
       });

       if(isDup){
           alert("Duplicate");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can just do: `$('.test').not(this)`

Comment: @Neal - I agree, that can be done. But I believe if we pass a selector it will be easy for `jQuery` to compare instead of object comparison.

Comment: but that involves a second search.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsFiddle problem is you didn't have jQuery selected.
http://jsfiddle.net/PLacj/7/